# What is the default saturation for a beamerposter HTML colour?

Tags: color, beamerposter, inkscape

I'm making a poster using `beamerposter`, with a background defined by a html colour code 682860. I am drawing my pictures in Inkscape, filling the background of the picture with the same colour code. It doesn't work as  I have to manually adjust the saturation in inkscape which adds an extra two letters to the html code, eg. 682860c6, and I can't get them to match up!

Is it be possible to make them the same?

Comment: It would probably help us to help you if you told us how you were defining the colour in your `.tex` file. A MWE would be even better

Comment: I am defining my colour in my .sty file using \definecolor{blockbg}{HTML}{682860}. In Inkscape in the "Fill and stroke" menu, there is a box where you can insert the "RGBA" number of the colour, but it is then necessary to manually adjust the saturation.

Comment: I have found a solution. Using the snipping tool in windows, I took a picture of the colour that Latex produced and then loaded it in Inkscape to see what it thought the colour was. The RGBA number was completely different to the one which I entered into Latex. I guess they must just be different things!

Comment: We'd like to keep answers separate from questions, so you should write a separate answer instead of adding your answer as a comment to the question. Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.

Comment: Without a proper example, I don't see this getting an answer. Please consider editing and adding perhaps a self answer.